# Remove image width and height from WordPress image URL

Tags: jquery, regex, wordpress, image, thumbnails

Is there a way to turn off automatic -widthxheight being added to my WordPress image URL? Like, for example;

http://xevens.com/projects/xe/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/alaska_winter_nights-1366x768-300x168.jpg
http://xevens.com/projects/xe/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/alaska_winter_nights-1366x768.jpg

That 300x168 is unnecessary to me in most cases. And now I need the image to be its original dimensions. If there's no way to do that, can you at least brew me a nice little REGEX so I can get rid of -300x168 via jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: so you always use the images in their original dimensions? check the functions.php for `add_image_size`

Comment: something like find: `-300x168\.jpg` replace `\.jpg`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
-\d+[Xx]\d+\.
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gJ0oD5/2)**

[image]

You can replace the matched content with a `.` as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Thanks! You're a savior. StackOverflow is probably about ready to block my account for asking "low quality" regex questions, but in truth you guys help save me from HOURS of frustration :)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few regex variations depending on the situation with the WordPress images.

## 1

If you want a regex which selects only the image name from resized images in the wp-content/uploads and EXCLUDES the resized portion, you could do something more specific:
[Working Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/b1T5Usv7Owxn2NlS)

```
\/wp-content\/uploads\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}/(.*)(?:-[0-9]{1,5}x[0-9]{1,5})(\..{2,4})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]
Group $1 selects the file name (excluding the resized part) and group $2 selects the extension

## 2

Or, if you were moving your library and wanted to change the URL even for non-resized images, but still need to exclude the resized portion of the filename:  [Working Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hWfgTSXIYB5h1YBM)

```
\/wp-content\/uploads\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}/(.*)(?:-[0-9]{1,5}x[0-9]{1,5})(\..{2,4})|\/wp-content\/uploads\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}/(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]
Group $1 selects the file name (excluding the resized part), group $2 selects the extension, and group $3 selects entire filenames for those files that don't have a resize.  If you output $1$2$3 it will either combine $1 and $2, or show $3 - so you always get the filename without the resized portion.

## 3

Or if you want to select only the resized portion of the filename for any of the image uploads: [Working Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CFvBclOQod1hYnuP)

```
\/wp-content\/uploads\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}/.*(-[0-9]{1,5}x[0-9]{1,5})\..{2,4}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]
Group $1 selects the resized portion of the files that are in the wp-content/uploads

## 4

Or perhaps you want to select the entire url for any images that are resized: [Working Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Z79vCqIVMKiRzGQE)

```
(\/wp-content\/uploads\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}/.*-[0-9]{1,5}x[0-9]{1,5}\..{2,4})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

$1 selects any url that contains the wp-content/uploads with any year/month folder and which has a resized image (ex: containing -123x456.jpg)

I used #2 above when setting up redirects for all the images when migrating a WordPress website.  We no longer wanted to use the YYYY/MM folders and we had different image resize proportions.  The regex allowed the old images to redirect to the full-size image so at least they aren't simply getting a 404.